# How should the flash tag be disambiguated?

Tags: discussion, tags

[flash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) is used for two unrelated meanings: Adobe Flash and flash memory. How should they be disambiguated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best course of action in this situation will be to have two separate tags.

[flash-memory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-memory) for questions related to well... flash memory. I see you have already tagged one of your questions with it.

[adobe-flash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) should be the tag used for Adobe Flash.

It appears that with the exception of one (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35990/can-you-tell-the-date-files-where-deleted-from-a-flash-drive) particular question, all the questions tagged with [flash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) is referring to Adobe Flash.

Comment: Thanks for going through the questions. With all [tag:flash] refering to Adobe Flash (let's count that closed, unanswered, -5 score question as deleted), we can keep the tag called [tag:flash]. I don't see another likely candidate for [tag:flash-memory].

Comment: What about Flash Gordon?  Clearly he is the answer to many security questions... Like how to save the world.